# Multi-threading Class in C++

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing

I wrote a C++ class which can take a vector of functions and their respective arguments and execute them in parallel and return a vector of results from its respective functions.

```cpp
// @file: mthread.hh
// @author: Tushar Chaurasia (Dark-CodeX)
// @license: This file is licensed under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3, 29 June 2007. You may obtain a copy of this license at https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html.

#ifndef MTHREAD_HH
#define MTHREAD_HH

#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

namespace openutils
{
    template <typename return_type, typename... args>
    class mthread
    {
    private:
        std::vector<return_type> ret_val;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    public:
        void execute_processes(const std::vector<std::function<return_type(args...)>> &functions, const std::vector<args> &...a);
        const std::vector<return_type> &get() const;
        std::vector<return_type> &get();
    };

    template <typename return_type, typename... args>
    void mthread<return_type, args...>::execute_processes(const std::vector<std::function<return_type(args...)>> &functions, const std::vector<args> &...a)
    {
        std::vector<return_type> temp_val(functions.size());        // pre allocate
        this->threads = std::vector<std::thread>(functions.size()); // pre allocate

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < functions.size(); i++)
        {
            this->threads[i] = std::thread([i, &temp_val, &functions, &a...]()
                                           { temp_val[i] = (functions[i](a[i]...)); });
        }

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->threads.size(); i++)
        {
            this->threads[i].join();
        }

        this->ret_val.swap(temp_val);
    }

    template <typename return_type, typename... args>
    const std::vector<return_type> &mthread<return_type, args...>::get() const
    {
        return this->ret_val;
    }

    template <typename return_type, typename... args>
    std::vector<return_type> &mthread<return_type, args...>::get()
    {
        return this->ret_val;
    }
}

#endif
```

The above library can be used as:

```cpp
int main()
{
    openutils::mthread<int, std::pair<int, int>> thread;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> args({{10, 20}, {5, 5}});

    thread.execute_processes({[](std::pair<int, int> x)
                              { return x.first + x.second; },
                              [](std::pair<int, int> x)
                              { return x.first - x.second; }},
                             args);

    std::vector<int> get = thread.get();

    for (const int &x : get)
        printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
30
0
```

Any suggestions, improvements are appreciated.

Comment: Read about: [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: Could've been a static function, returning ret_val instead of storing it somewhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### License

Just as a heads up.

```
// @license: This file is licensed under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3, 29 June 2007. You may obtain a copy of this license at https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html.
```

You have now all licensed this file under `Creative Commons`. There is a link at the bottom of the page. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

### Overview

OK. Nice try, if you are just experimenting.
**BUT** this is a bad idea.

I have a couple of issues with your implementation.

1: Threads are expensive to create.
2: There is no point in making more threads than you have processors. You are just doing busy work swapping between threads when you can simply spend time on one thread.

Given the above two. What you normally do is create a "Work" queue onto which you add work items. Simple interface `run()` the object has all the parameters embedded. Then you create a "Thread Pool", a set of thread objects(about the number of processors on your hardware). Each thread in the pool will execute a unique work item on the "Work" queue when finished it will get the next item or wait until another one is added.

Do a search for thread groups: [Thread Pool in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/180866/507)

But even thread pools are obsolete. The standard already provides an abstract mechanism to do this. `std::async`. Here you create an item of work and get a promise back. When the work item is finished the promise contains the result (or exception). Behind the sense the standard can create a thread pool for you.

### CodeReview

The term `MTHREAD` seems very likely to be used previously. I would add the namespace into the include guard to try and make it more unique.

```
#ifndef MTHREAD_HH
#define MTHREAD_HH
```

---

The design of the class seems a bit odd.

```
    template <typename return_type, typename... args>
    class mthread
    {
    private:
        std::vector<return_type> ret_val;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    public:
        void execute_processes(const std::vector<std::function<return_type(args...)>> &functions, const std::vector<args> &...a);
        const std::vector<return_type> &get() const;
        std::vector<return_type> &get();
    };
```

There is no constructor. But you start the execution by calling `execute_processes()` and passing all the values that are needed. Seems like this could be better designed as static method that simply returns the results.

So rather than:

```
thread.execute_processes({[](std::pair<int, int> x)
                          { return x.first + x.second; },
                          [](std::pair<int, int> x)
                          { return x.first - x.second; }},
                         args);

std::vector<int> get = thread.get();
```

I would want to use it like:

```
std::vector<int> get = 
mthread::execute_processes({[](std::pair<int, int> x)
                          { return x.first + x.second; },
                          [](std::pair<int, int> x)
                          { return x.first - x.second; }},
                         args);
```

---

Don't use `this->`

If you have to use `this->` it means you have accidently shadowed a member variable with a local variable and you need to disambiguify the two members. The trouble is the compiler can not tell when you get it wrong.

So better solution is to always make your identifiers unique.

Comment: Also, I am creating this class as I have to parse a file, but if life is larger it takes too much time, hence I want to parse the file in chunks.

Comment: "But even thread pools are obsolete. The standard already provides an abstract mechanism to do this. std::async." In the imperfect world we live in, `std::async` does not render thread pools obsolete - libstdc++, for example, has it launch a new thread for every call to it. However, future/promise interface can (and often is) utilized in modern thread pool libraries.

Comment: Does any of the popular stdlib implementations use thread pools for std::async?

Comment: _"Don't use this->"_ not a C++ programmer but I see nothing wrong with using `this->`, actually, I prefer it because it's more "precise" i.e. it's always clear you're referencing an instance variable.

Comment: @Marco I agree with you as a C++ programmer, I don't see any valid reason to avoid `this->` instead of someone's personal choice. If `this->` is bad it should not exist in c++ compilers.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Just because the compiler _can_ do something doesn't mean you should do it. See also: [GOTO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/868546). There is _a lot_ of historical backwards compatibility built into the compiler. The C++ standards body rarely removes capabilities with the general philosophy that any valid, compilable, standards-compliant code written at any point in time should still compile later on. I think Martin provides a very clear reason why it is potentially dangerous. "Accidently shadowed a variable" is one of those very painful, obscure bugs to solve.

Comment: @Marco The problem is the compiler can not tell when you don't need it so you are opening yourself upto to errors that can not be detected by the compiler. You can turn on compiler warnings to tell you when you have shadowed a variable though which removes the need to worry about the situation of needing `this->` entirely.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Martin York's answer:

## Make it more generic

Your code works if the data is stored in `std::vector`s, but what if it was stored in a `std::array`, `std::list` or any other container type? You don't really care about the exact container type, just that you can iterate over them. Consider STL algorithms like [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), or the C++20 ranges versions like [`std::ranges::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/transform), except instead of applying one functions to a range of elements, you want to apply a range of functions on a range of elements. So modelling it on the standard library's algorithms, you could write something like:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range Input,
         std::ranges::weakly_incrementable Output,
         std::ranges::input_range Functions>
void parallel_transform(Input&& input, Output output, Functions&& functions) {
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    auto function_it = functions.begin();
    for (auto& value: input) {
        output.emplace_back();
        threads.emplace_back([](const auto& value, auto& result, auto function) {
             result = std::invoke(function, value);
        }, std::cref(value), std::ref(output.back()), *function_it++);
    }
}
```

You'd use it like so:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> args({{10, 20}, {5, 5}});
std::vector<int> result;
std::vector<std::function<int(std::pair<int,int>)>> functions{
    [](std::pair<int, int> x){ return x.first + x.second; },
    [](std::pair<int, int> x){ return x.first - x.second; },
};

parallel_transform(args, std::back_inserter(result), functions);

for (int x: result)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
```

The small drawback is that you need to create the output container and a container of functions up front.

## What about exceptions?

One problem you have with threads is that an exception can happen inside a thread. But how do you communicate that back to the caller? Martin York already hinted about `std::async()`. This functions solves the issue by returning a `std::future`, which will get notified of exceptions thrown in the async task. When calling [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) on the `std::future`, the expection is rethrown, so the caller can then deal with it.