# Simple versatile thread pool

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

Here's a rather hastily made thread pool to suit my requirements and even for my future projects. It is working fine and executing tasks as intended but I want to improve more and I am not sure if it's the proper way to design a thread-pool as I am a self taught enthusiast, and rather weak as a language lawyer.

Tasks are stored in the queue. They are executed in order only when an idle thread is available from the pool. New tasks can be pushed into the queue. To initialize the pool, one has to specify the total number of threads and a `bool` variable which will be used to terminate the pool and threads gracefully.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>    
#include <chrono>    
#include <mutex>    
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

typedef function<void(void)> task_t;

class thread_t
{
public:
    thread_t(int id, bool& running, condition_variable& cv)
        :id_(id)
        , running_(running)
        , idle_notify_cv_(cv)
    {
        idle_ = true;
        thread_ = new thread([=]() { run(); });
    }

    ~thread_t()
    {
        notify();
        cout << id_ << "  stopping \n";
        thread_->join();
    }

    void push(task_t task)
    {
        task_ = task;
        idle_ = false;
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    void notify()
    {
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    bool is_idle() const
    {
        return idle_;
    }
    int get_id() const
    {
        return id_;
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        cout << id_ << "  starting  \n";
        while (running_)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu_);
            cv_.wait(lock, [=]() { return idle_ == false || !running_; });
            if (!running_) return;
            task_();
            cout << id_ << " :work done  \n";
            idle_ = true;
            idle_notify_cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }
private:
    condition_variable& idle_notify_cv_;
    mutex mu_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    task_t task_;
    thread* thread_;
    bool idle_;
    int id_;
    bool& running_;
};

class pool
{
public:
    pool(int n, bool& running)
        :nthreads_(n)
        ,running_(running)
    {
        if (n > std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) nthreads_ = n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            threads_.push_back(make_unique<thread_t >(i, running_, idle_notify_cv_));
        }

        pool_thread_ = new thread([=]() { run(); });
    }

    void push(task_t task)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(write_queue_mu_);
        tasks_.push(task);
        idle_notify_cv_.notify_one();
    }

    int get_idle()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nthreads_; i++)
        {
            if (threads_[i]->is_idle())
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void run()
    {
        cout << " pool thread started \n " ;
        while (running_)
        {
            int idle;
            if (!tasks_.empty() && (idle = get_idle()) != -1)
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(write_queue_mu_);
                idle_notify_cv_.wait(lock, [=]() { return idle != -1 || !running_; });
                if (!running_) return;
                auto task = tasks_.front();
                tasks_.pop(); 
                lock.unlock();
                cout << " thread# " << threads_[idle]->get_id() << " assigned a task \n";
                threads_[idle]->push(task);
            }
        }
    }


    ~pool()
    {
        pool_thread_->join();
        cout << " thread pool destroyed \n ";
    }

private:
    mutex write_queue_mu_;
    queue<task_t> tasks_;
    vector<unique_ptr<thread_t>> threads_;
    int nthreads_;
    bool& running_;
    condition_variable idle_notify_cv_;
    thread* pool_thread_;
};



int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    pool pool1(2, running);

    task_t task1 = []()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2s));
        cout << " Task 1 executed \n";
    };

    task_t task2 = []()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1s));
        cout << " Task 2 executed \n";
    };

    task_t task3= []()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2s));
        cout << " Task 3 executed \n";
    };

    task_t task4 = []()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1s));
        cout << " Task 4 executed \n";
    };

    pool1.push(task1);
    pool1.push(task2);
    pool1.push(task3);
    pool1.push(task4);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5s));
    running = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers). Since I've removed that section from my UB section it's fine since nothing was invalidated, but please keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Zeta: Ok I got it, new to codereview

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: calls new but not delete!

Comment: has pointers but does not follow rule of three

Comment: has pointers but does not need them. (you can move threads),

Comment: The use of a `pool` thread to assign work is bad idea. It will slow down the code immensely because of the coordination required.

Comment: take a look at this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47122/507

Comment: @MartinYork: Yes, the threads should be deleted once they joined.Please take a look at the simple analysis ( 2nd reply). I prefer thread pool to launching individual threads since  creating a new thread has huge time cost. In a huge multi-threaded application, we may run out of threads .Thread pool serializes to some extend reducing use of locks and mutexes at times.

Comment: @seccpur: Yes threads should be deleted once they are joined. unfortunately they are not.

Comment: @seccpur: My comment about the `pool` thread is that it is not needed to implement a thread pool. In fact the use of a `pool` thread to assign the work to the other threads is going to be a significant performance degradation because of all the extra synchronization that is required.

Comment: @seccpur: Which is why I also provided a link to an example thread pool that does not use a `pool` thread. But rather each thread get its work object directly from the queue when it finishes the last piece of work (or waits for work to become available).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Undefined behaviour

Your code contains undefined behaviour due to data races. The read-access on `thread_t::idle_` in `thread_t::is_idle` isn't synchronized with possible write-access in `thread_t::run`. That's a data race. Same holds for `thread_t::push`. I can `push` a new task while the old one is currently processed.

## Don't use `using namespace std`

Do not use `using namespace std` if your names are likely to collide with the ones from the standard library, and *never* use it in a header. You had to use `thread_t` since `std::thread` already exists. However, names that end with `_t` are reserved by POSIX. That's usually ignored, though.

## Overall design

Your overall design seems sound, but some functions seem strange. Why is `thread_t::notify()` part of the public interface? Does `pool::get_idle` return the number of idle threads or the first id? Should a user be able to call `pool::run()` or `thread_t::run()`?

Move those functions into the `private` section. Make your classes easy to use and hard to misuse.

By the way, `pool::run` might contain a bug. After `idle != -1` (in `if`), the lambda takes `idle` by copy (`[=]`). `idle`'s value will never change at that point, so the check in the lambda is superfluous.

## Delete forbidden functions

`thread_t`'s copy constructor should get explicitly deleted, as well as its copy assignment. Depending on your use case, you maybe even want to prevent moves:

```
thread_t(thread_t&&) = delete;
thread_t(const thread_t&) = delete;
thread_t& operator=(thread_t&&) = delete;
thread_t& operator=(const thread_t&) = delete;
```

## Add documentation

This depends on whether you want to re-use your code in a (future) project, but what is currently clear to you might not be as clear in some days/weeks/months. While we're at it, use a code formatter. Some of your single-statement `if`s have braces, other's dont, e.g.

```
        // nice
        if (threads_[i]->is_idle())
        {
            return i;
        }
```

vs

```
    // not so nice :(
    if (n > std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) nthreads_ = n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
```

Other than that you stuck to a single indentation/braces style, which is great.

## Reduce complexity

You have both `idle_notify_cv_` as a reference and `cv_` as a referee. I *guess* you had two `std::condition_variable`s at first and then removed one. If that's the case, I suggest you to remove one of them next time. The compiler will tell you where the variable has been used and you can do a case-by-case decision whether it still needs to get checked or can get removed.

## Split functionality

This is likely a toy program for you to fiddle with `std::thread`, but for a library split your functionality into several files, e.g.

```
thread.h
thread.cpp
thread_pool.h
thread_pool.cpp
```

If you split your implementation from your header, the recompilation time should get down a lot if your application grows in size. It won't be noticeable on your current program, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick inputs  I will definitely work on that.

Comment: Are you sure about UB? There is `idle = get_idle()` assignment.

Comment: @vnp missed that. Didn't expect a side-effect in that `if`. However, then `idle` will never be `-1` since it's taken by copy. Hm....

Comment: @Zeta: All your inputs are solid, can't be more better, I am super excited .

Comment: thread_t::notify() signals the thread-pool that an executor is over and if tasks are in queue, they can be executed also.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `operator=(thread_t&) = delete;` instead of just `operator`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a test analysis of the above thread pool by pushing 100 tasks in the pool.

The result shows multi-threaded  is  much faster (x10 in this example) than ordinary function call , but in some simple cases it may vary. I want to reserve 1-2 threads in the pool for critical time bound tasks in the next step.

I can't edit my post, but   `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1))` may inserted in pool::run() while loop to prevent blocking during task push

```
int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    thread_pool pool(10, running);

    task_t task = []()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    };

    auto start =  std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
    for(int i= 0;i<100;i++)
        pool.push_task(task);
    while (!pool.empty())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(30));
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout <<"Multithreaded  took "<< (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start)).count()/1000 << " sec\n";


    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        task();
    stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout <<"Plain function took "<< (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start)).count()/1000 << " sec\n";


    running = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the interesting result ( excluding pool setup time):
[image]

Comment: As the sleep does no work, it allows the core to be assigned to a new thread. Therefore all 100 sleeps can run in parallel (as no work is being done any of them). Therefore an optimal implementation should finish in slightly over 100 ms. A run time of 1 second is extremely slow in my opinion for this test. Just saw that you only use 10 threads. So you get the expected result for doing no work (as it can easily run 10 no work threads in parallel). I don't think this test proves much.

Answer (score 0):

One very important issue hasn't been mentioned so far. You should definitively redesign the active wait loop when waiting for a thread in `run` method:

```
void run()
{
    while (running_)
    {
        if (!tasks_.empty() && (idle = get_idle()) != -1)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This active loop consumes CPU time when there is a task pending but no available worker thread. So not only all the workers are busy doing their work, but you also keeps busy the dispatcher. Better approach is to use some signalling mechanism that will pause your `run` method and resume when some of tasks completes.

And one more detail. Passing of reference `running` flag to `pool` constructor is basically not a good idea. Please note if you pass `false` to constructor and later you decide to activate your pool by changing the reference, it will silently fail - nothing starts `run` method again. You should consider implementing the enable/disable logic in public methods rather than simple boolean flag.

Comment: Nice catch. I miss that.